# complex custom schema for xml processing in spark

Tags: xml, scala, apache-spark, dataset

I am trying to write custom schema for spark to load xml file. In my case i need to access two tags i.e.: `related-publication` and `us-provisional-application`  under `us-related-documents` tag

Here is my data structure:

```
 us-related-documents: struct (nullable = true)
| 
| |-- related-publication: array (nullable = true)
| | |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
| | | |-- document-id: struct (nullable = true)
| | | | |-- country: string (nullable = true)
| | | | |-- date: long (nullable = true)
| | | | |-- doc-number: long (nullable = true)
| | | | |-- kind: string (nullable = true)
| |-- us-provisional-application: array (nullable = true)
| | |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
| | | |-- document-id: struct (nullable = true)
| | | | |-- country: string (nullable = true)
| | | | |-- date: long (nullable = true)
| | | | |-- doc-number: long (nullable = true)
```

Here is my code for accessing one tag:

```
    StructField("us-related-documents", StructType(
List(StructField("us-provisional-application",StructType(
List(StructField("document-id",
ArrayType(StructType(
List(
StructField("doc-number", StringType, nullable = true),
StructField("country", StringType, nullable = true),
StructField("kind", StringType, nullable = true),
StructField("date", LongType, nullable = true),
StructField("name", StringType, nullable = true)
)
))))
)))
))
```

Its failing when I attempt to add another tag to the above schema.
How can I access the remaining tag?

Comment: You forgot to add the error to the question

Answer (score 1):

> Here is my code for accessing one tag

First, that's the Dataset schema, not code to access anything. You should be using the `select()` methods of the Dataset object, or SparkSQL to access data.

For example

```
df.select($"us-related-documents.related-publication")
```

---

I'm not sure why you are trying to rebuild the StructType object of the schema, but that code does not match the printed schema...

`us-provisional-application` needs to be an `ArrayType`, not a `StructType`.

`document-id` is a struct, not an array

Your Scala code more closely matches the `related-publication` struct anyway, so that's probably the first error.

`doc-number` is a long, not a string

You also missed the `element` struct of the schema and none of the struct fields are called `name`

---

After you fix these, please tell us what your errors actually are

Comment: It's not any solution or answer. It looks like a prediction or assumption. Therefore it's not the answer.

Comment: Prediction or assumption? OP's struct is clearly incorrect. Which I have pointed out

Comment: @cricket_007 , after your mentioned changes i cross-checked my output and its not correct.can you please write the schema for one tag so that i can apply it for another tags?

Comment: Your dataset already has a schema. I don't understand what you're trying to do exactly

Answer (score -2):

You have to use [spark-xml](https://github.com/databricks/spark-xml) library to parse the XML file

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
import com.databricks.spark.xml._

val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)
val df = sqlContext.read
  .option("rowTag", "book")
  .xml("books.xml")

val selectedData = df.select("author", "_id")
selectedData.write
  .option("rootTag", "books")
  .option("rowTag", "book")
  .xml("newbooks.xml")
```

Alternatively you can specify the format to use instead:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext

val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)
val df = sqlContext.read
  .format("com.databricks.spark.xml")
  .option("rowTag", "book")
  .load("books.xml")

val selectedData = df.select("author", "_id")
selectedData.write
  .format("com.databricks.spark.xml")
  .option("rootTag", "books")
  .option("rowTag", "book")
  .save("newbooks.xml")
```

You can manually specify the schema when reading data:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{StructType, StructField, StringType, DoubleType};

val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)
val customSchema = StructType(Array(
  StructField("_id", StringType, nullable = true),
  StructField("author", StringType, nullable = true),
  StructField("description", StringType, nullable = true),
  StructField("genre", StringType ,nullable = true),
  StructField("price", DoubleType, nullable = true),
  StructField("publish_date", StringType, nullable = true),
  StructField("title", StringType, nullable = true)))


val df = sqlContext.read
  .format("com.databricks.spark.xml")
  .option("rowTag", "book")
  .schema(customSchema)
  .load("books.xml")

val selectedData = df.select("author", "_id")
selectedData.write
  .format("com.databricks.spark.xml")
  .option("rootTag", "books")
  .option("rowTag", "book")
  .save("newbooks.xml")
```

Comment: Hi @Bhaskar Das, i need to access nested two nested array fields from root tag(struct tag), i was able to access to access one array tag and failed to access second one.

Comment: If you want to process XML dataset then the easiest way is to use API in Scala with Spark.

Comment: Yes i am also using scala API. in my case, i need to access multiple nested values

Comment: This looks copied straight from the documentation, therefore not answering the question

Comment: Yes I have copied from the documentation because it's the straight way have to follow to achieve the answer.

Comment: How does your answer solve the problem in the question of "i need to access two tags, `related-publication` and `us-provisional-application`"?