# Spark-XML; Reading from S3 using explicit schema on read. Problem with Array Type in XML

Tags: xml, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-xml

I am attempting to the spark-xml library through the Scala Spark API (https://github.com/databricks/spark-xml) in order to read a large amount of XML files from S3.

- The schema across the XML files in S3 differs such that simply reading them all at once results in certain fields becoming corrupted on read. I believe this is due to the schema inconsistencies across the XML files, which are to a very large extent identical in schema
- because of this, I am specifying the Tags I would like to extract explicitly in a schema object
- I am having issues with the syntax used to define the schema when it comes to array types.
- you can see the schema of the XML below. For the purposes of this question, I am just looking to extract the follwing:

  - _ProgramInfoID
  - _VALUE (contained within the **array type** object, Line)

appreciate any feedback here!

The following code example extracts the **_ProgramInfoID** field only

```
val schema = StructType(
                // BROACAST METADATA
                Array(StructField("BroadcastMetadata",StructType(
                    // PROGRAM INFO
                    Array(StructField("ProgramInfo", StructType(
                        Array(StructField("_ProgramInfoID", StringType, nullable = true))
                        )))
                    ))),                  
                )
```

The following attempts to read both **ProgramInfoID and _VALUE** but runs into an error just upon trying to define the schema object

```
val schema = StructType(
                // BROACAST METADATA
                Array(StructField("BroadcastMetadata",StructType(
                    // PROGRAM INFO
                    Array(StructField("ProgramInfo", StructType(
                        Array(StructField("_ProgramInfoID", StringType, nullable = true))
                        )))

                    ))),
                
                // LINES
                Array(StructField("Lines", StructType(
                    // Line 
                      ArrayType(StructField("Line", StructType(
                          Array(StructField("element", StructType(
                            Array(StructField("_VALUE", StringType, nullable = true))
                                ))))))
                    )))
                                 
                                    
                
                )
```

**Error:**

```
<console>:45: error: type mismatch;
 found   : org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructField
 required: org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataType
                             ArrayType(StructField("Line", StructType(
```

I realize that this is a syntax error, but I haven't been able to find good documentation on how to translate the schema I see below into the schema involving Spark types like ArrayType, StructField, and StructType.

**related question** involving Array Type objects in XML: [complex custom schema for xml processing in spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48581632/complex-custom-schema-for-xml-processing-in-spark)

However, I haven't been able to resolve this question using the solutions there.

**XML Sample Data Schema**

```
root
 |-- BroadcastMetadata: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- ExtendedProgramInfo: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- Schedule: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- AiringType: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- PartNumber: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- Program: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- AdditionalProgramURL: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- AliasTitle: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- Delta: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- Descriptions: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- ProgramDescription: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- Delta: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- _ProgramID: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- _RoviRemotePath: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- EpisodeNumber: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- EpisodeTitle: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- EventDate: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- Genres: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- ProgramGenre: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- Delta: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- Genre: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- _RoviRemotePath: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- Grid2Title: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- GridTitle: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- ProgramOriginalCountry: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- Delta: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- _RoviRemotePath: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- ProgramOriginalLanguage: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- Delta: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- _RoviRemotePath: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- RecordDateTime: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- Syndicated: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- TVRatings: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- ProgramTVRating: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- Delta: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- _RoviRemotePath: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- ThreeDLevel: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- TitleParentID: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- _RoviRemotePath: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- ProgramID: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- ProgramShowingType: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- RecordDateTime: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- _ScheduleID: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- Market: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- Country: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- _MarketName: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- ProgramInfo: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- CC: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- Category: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- _ProgramInfoID: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- Station: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- Active: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- _UniqueIdentifier: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- TranscriptUrl: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- ViewershipData: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Lines: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- Line: array (nullable = true) --> SEE ARRAY TYPE HERE
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- _LineDateTime: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- _StationGUID: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- _StationID: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- _UTCDelta: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- _UTCLineDateTime: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- _VALUE: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _BreakType: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _Duration: double (nullable = true)
 |-- _PageID: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _StationGUID: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _StationID: long (nullable = true)
```

I appreciate any help here, thank you!!